# Laravel 5.4 composer error

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am facing a strange issue with `Laravel 5.4.9`. 
I tried to install a repository instead might have made a mess by
installing it as a controller. Now when I type `php artisan route:list`, I am getting this error:

> [ReflectionException]
>   Class App\Http\Controllers\ProjectRepositoryInterface does not exist.

This ProjectRepositoryInterface is in repository folder and it works normal.

I want to know where the controller classes are registered and stored? Are they 
stored in a file (like we bind the repository and interface in the app service provider file).

How to get rid of this error?

Comment: Clear your log file, try again and then post your log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `composer dump-autoload` to clear the composer reference to the old file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have done dump-autoload but the error still persists. Where is the log file located?

Comment: Thanks to all of you. I have done about two three times and the error is gone.

Comment: If your error is resolved then you can accept the answer @user6404606